# How to edit Zepellin config and set the notebook storage?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to change the location where Zeppelin stores my notebooks.

If I navigate to notebooksRepos I can provide the path of my project, but it gets overridden with defaults when I reset the server. 
http://localhost:8080/#/notebookRepos
[image]

The configure page does not seem editable from the UI.
http://localhost:8080/#/configuration

[image]

**taking a look at raw config files**

> https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/setup/operation/configuration.html#zeppelin-properties

```
$ brew install apache-zeppelin
$ cd ~/usr/local/Cellar/apache-zeppelin/0.8.1/libexec/conf
$ ls

configuration.xsl
interpreter.json
log4j_yarn_cluster.properties 
zeppelin-env.cmd.template     
zeppelin-site.xml.template
interpreter-list              
log4j.properties              
shiro.ini.template            
zeppelin-env.sh.template <-- why .template?
```

^ no sign of `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` or `conf/zeppelin-site.xml`

---

UPDATE: I've tried inserting my path via `nano` in the `value` of the various conf files, but the config UI does not show my updated values.

```
$ mv zeppelin-env.sh.template zeppelin-env.sh
$ nano zeppelin-env.sh

export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR="/Users/me/Desktop/my_project"

$ zeppelin-daemon.sh stop
$ zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

Comment: https://docs.zepl.com/guide/zeppelin_integration/

Comment: https://www.datageekinme.com/setup/setting-up-my-mac-zeppelin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ughh. I was editing the .sh file, but was failing to remove the comment syntax at the start of the line.

```
$ cd ~/usr/local/Cellar/apache-zeppelin/0.8.1/libexec/conf
$ cp zeppelin-env.sh.template zeppelin-env.sh
$ nano zeppelin-env.sh
```

**inside .sh file**

```
# export ZEPPELIN_WAR_TEMPDIR                   # The location of jetty temporary directory.

export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR=/Users/me/Desktop/my_proj/notebooks
```

^ removed #. no " needed for strings.

then restart server and go to http://localhost:8080/#/configuration to see it!